# Chrome extension automatic update not working

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I configured the update url as following:

```
"update_url": "https://www.myextension.host.com/updates.xml"
```

And the updates.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<gupdate xmlns='http://www.google.com/update2/response' protocol='2.0'>
  <app appid='aplfhldgnogkgfjopdbppahookjpfpad'>
    <updatecheck codebase='https://www.myextension.host.com/updateExtension/chrome_2.0.crx' version='2.0' />
  </app>
</gupdate>
```

But when I installed the extension and click the update now, nothing happened, the server does not detect the request for the updates.xml file either.

I started chrome with

```
chrome.exe --enable-logging --log-level=2
```

but cannot find any error log about the update. Well I did see some logs but I'm not sure it's related or not. Post below too:

```
[5468:1956:0515/114000:ERROR:accelerated_surface_win.cc(208)] Reseting D3D device
[5468:188:0515/114003:ERROR:textfield.h(156)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[5468:428:0515/114007:ERROR:accelerated_surface_win.cc(208)] Reseting D3D device
[4500:476:0515/114131:ERROR:ipc_channel_win.cc(132)] pipe error: 109
[5468:3560:0515/114131:ERROR:accelerated_surface_win.cc(208)] Reseting D3D device
[5468:3048:0515/114218:ERROR:accelerated_surface_win.cc(208)] Reseting D3D device
[5676:1276:0515/120110:ERROR:ipc_channel_win.cc(132)] pipe error: 109
[3596:6072:0515/120540:ERROR:ipc_channel_win.cc(132)] pipe error: 109
```

Is there any debug way to better debug the update operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get debugging information about the extension's updater process, start Chrome / Chromium with the following command:

```
chrome.exe --vmodule=extension_updater=2 --enable-logging
```

After starting Chrome, a log file called `chrome_debug.log` will be created in your user profile directory.

Without any other information, I guess that you've either got a typo in the extension ID or in the update URL. If your extension still doesn't install after fixing this issue, check whether the crx file is served with the `application/x-chrome-extension` MIME-type.

Comment: Great, thanks, by enabling the log, I got log: Starting update check 0
[6500:6820:0516/172222:VERBOSE2:extension_updater.cc(309)] Extension ahfgeienlihckogmohjhadlkjgocpleb is not auto updateable, sorry, let me check more.

Comment: @user2381038 That's not your extension. You can expect any of the errors defined at [extension_updater.cc](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/browser/extensions/updater/extension_updater.cc&q=extension_updater.cc&sq=package:chromium&type=cs) (Ctrl+F `VLOG`).

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong log. Mine extension also has the log: Extension aplfhldgnogkgfjopdbppahookjpfpad is not auto updateable

Comment: How did you install the extension?

Comment: Extensions activated in that way are exempt from auto-update. Imagine that you're developing an extension, then press Update, to see your development version nuked and replaced with an old upload. You have to install the extension as a CRX file in order to get auto-update to work.

Comment: Reasonable, but after I install with the crx and click update, I cannot see any log about my extension's update. Just leave no evidence..

Comment: Bump your version. I only saw logs for extensions which were actually updated.

Comment: Thank you for following this question! I changed the version in manifest file and in the updates.xml file too. But I will check again!

Comment: I really hoped that it's caused by my typo or forgot to change version. But I checked many times and did create two different versions 1.0 and 2.0 by setting the version attr in manifest.json file and modified the version in the updates.xml to 2.0. But I still cannot see any log. Even when the host server is down, no log shown up which I think should have log.

Comment: Is there any special points I should pay attention to with https protocol?

Comment: Use valid certificates, etc. (that's obvious). Try using Wireshark to monitor the network during such an update.

Comment: Yeah, thanks a ton, I have made some stupid mistakes, I packed the extension with different keys, (I really did this...) The update is triggered, I saw log but still I didn't see the version up..'https://localhost:8443/tools/chrome_2.0.crx written to C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\FC32.tmp
[5056:4672:0517/144750:VERBOSE2:extension_updater.cc(601)] updating klaiofjmoinchdnpbphaloggnolhaeap with C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\FC32.tmp
[5056:4672:0517/144750:VERBOSE2:extension_updater.cc(692)] Finished update check 27', content type: Content-Type:application/x-chrome-extension verified

Comment: I repacked my extension and do the whole process again and it's updated. Thanks for your help!